# verb "to accent" in the meaning to pronounce in a non-native like manner

Tags: synonyms

What synonyms can be used for the verb "to accent" in the meaning *to pronounce in a non-native like manner*? For example:

> Of the three target sounds [bla], [bla] and [bla] two segments were ”accented” by the subjects of the experiment as [bla*] and [bla*].

I am writing a paper on a foreign accent and have to describe typical mistakes in pronunciation.

Comment: Please edit your question and add several actual examples, for example by listing numerous words often mispronounced, or by listing with their mispronunciations a few words often mispronounced.

Comment: another example:What is only evident from our data is that [ø̞] is most often accented as [y].

Comment: 'mispronounced'?

Comment: and here accented is ambiguous, since readers may think of "word stress"

Comment: Quite a good idea! This one did not come into my head. Thanks.

Comment: Native BrE speaker here. I would say that the word "accented" in your example sentence is not ambiguous, just wrong. "Accent" when used as a verb means to stress, e.g. to accent a particular syllable. (I suppose it could also mean "to write an accent above a letter, e.g. to turn a written "e" into "é".) I've never heard "to accent" used to mean "to pronounce in a foreign manner." I would say "to pronounce incorrectly", "to mispronounce", "to pronounce with a foreign/non-native accent". I don't think there's a single word that captures what you're looking for.

Comment: Aaaand I just realised your question is nearly five years old. I'm not sure how I ended up here.

Answer (score 3):

Since your sentence gives the actual pronunciation, the verb doesn't need to qualify it. Simply use the verb *pronounced.*

> *...two segments were pronounced by the subjects of the experiment as
>   [x] and [y]*

.

Answer (score 0):

A linguistic accent versus a grammatical accent.

Unfortunately there isn't a succinct specialized term to differentiate one from the other. Although it is not very elegant, modifying the verb seems straightforward enough. It is almost idiomatic but still not quite. Speech pattern is the closest in practical terms but is awkward to employ as a verb. Delineating the various aspects of what an "accent" is - linguistically - will give enough proper definition to charge the term you select with the meaning you outline.

Dialect, pronunciation, speech pattern, colloquial, idiomatic.. Also making the point of indicating up front that it is NOT meant grammatically.

Even "dialectal accenting/accentuation" works and isn't too awkward.

Homophones can get slippery every once in a while..